# Mapping XML data to class in C#

Tags: c#, xml, mapping

If I have an external XML feed and an internal class, what is the best way to automatically read the feed and map the data to new instances of the class?

So if the xml feed is like

```
<people>
   <person>
      <name>Bob</name>
   </person>
    <person>
      <name>Bill</name>
   </person>
</people>
```

And my class Person has a property Name. Right now I am stepping through with XmlReader but this seems inefficient

Comment: In which way is your current implementation 'inefficient'? Performace/Code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to map xml into a class in c# is using xml serialization. The -.Net framework comes with everything you need.
The problem is, that your xml need to be in the rigth format to be read by the deserializer.

**Serialization Example:**

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
  TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("people.xml");
  serializer.Serialize(textWriter, people);
  textWriter.Close();
```

**Deserialization Example**

```
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
   TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("people.xml");
   List<Person> people; 
   people= (List<Person>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
   textReader.Close();
```

**XML Result**

The xml should look like this (I didn't test it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Person>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Bill</Name>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

Comment: I am familiar with Serialization, but I have no control over the format of the XML feed

Comment: If you "have no control" over the source format, then you will have to parse the feed yourself. Anything else is foolhardy. XmlReader is perfectly suited to doing that.